# transfer the date format from model in adapter

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, adapter

I am working on the model to retrieve the string called "review_time" with this format:
**Sun May 03 21:41:46 PDT 2020**

The review_time has been stored in model successfully. I want to set the string to "May 03 ,2020"

here is what I have in the adapter onBindViewHolder:

```
//recursive all string, ex. Sun May 03 21:41:46 PDT 2020
String oldstring = model.getReview_time(); 
DateTimeFormatterBuilder  df = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("MMM DD, YYYY"); //May 03, 2020
Log.d("comment_adapter", df.toString());
```

How can I recursive all string to the format ("MMM DD, YYYY"). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like below while you set your new date formatted value

```
String js="Sun May 03 21:41:46 PDT 2020";//model.getReview_time()
Date dt=new Date(js);
LocalDateTime localDateTime=dt.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
obj.setNewDateValue(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy")));
```

Comment: It works! In last line, I use `String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(dt);` to substitute setNewDateValue. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to use DateTimeFormatter over SimpledateFormat as that class is outdated.